# How can I compile C++ code and link it to a running program?

Tags: c++, plugins, compilation, linker

I have a program with an interface where the user can write code.
Is there anyway I could compile, link and execute this code in the actual running program?

Comment: Yes it's possible. That's what my IDE does.

Comment: ok, how? I know it must be complicated.

Comment: We need a bit more details. Do you absolutely want your user to write C++? Typically, that type of scripting is done with Python, LUA or Javascript. (assuming you mean injecting more code into the app after it has been delivered in binary form)

Comment: You will need a compiler for that. It could be done by running the compiler as external process creating a dynamic library which would the main program load then. It would require to have the compiler installed on the user's machine, which might not be the case for Windows by default. Also good luck pushing it through user's anti-virus programs.

Comment: let's say we have an instance _textbox_ that can return the code written by the user while the program is running. All i want to achieve is something that can look like `auto lambda = compile(textbox.getText());`    `if(lambda.ready()) lambda();`

Comment: @Quimby That's why I hate windows.

Comment: @Elirovi I doubt that. Also what would the lambda do? It can't  easily communicate with the main program anyway.

Comment: Even if I make my own compiler in the program and manage to generate a lib or a dll or whatever, how can it be linked into a running program?

Comment: @Elirovi It won't be linked, just loaded into the memory and you can query .dll/.so for the list of exported symbols. See POSIX functions dlopen(), dlsym()  on UNIX. Second will return e.g a function pointer which can call the function from the library if you know its name and type. Still, getting this setup working properly is much harder than just using LUA.